# React swallows onClick event on li element

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `react-window` to optimize a custom dropdown menu component. The dropdown's menu uses the `List` component from `react-window` to render a `ul`, and the item component passed to the `List` renders an `li` element with an `onClick` handler assigned (to close the menu and pick an item). The dropdown component worked fine before I used `react-window`, but after switching, the `onClick` handler does not fire the first time each `li` element is clicked.

Investigating the `li` in Chrome's dev tools revealed that after the `li` node is first mounted, React attaches an noop event handler to the node's `onclick` property, apparently due to some iOS Safari bug ([here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/c954efa70f44a44be9c33c60c57f87bea6f40a10/packages/react-dom/src/client/ReactDOMComponent.js#L276-L287)). After clicking the node once, this goes away and my `onClick` handler fires properly.

If I change the event to `onMouseUp`, it works fine, but I shouldn't have to do that; I should be able to use `onClick` and have it fire reliably.

I'd like to file a bug report on this, but I'm not entirely sure if it's React's fault or `react-window`'s fault. I looked through the source of `react-window` and it doesn't seem to do anything strange to render the item component; it just uses `createElement`. Obviously `onClick` events work for some elements, including my `li` elements before I moved to `react-window`...somehow the noop event handler wasn't affecting them beforehand.

Is anyone else familiar with this particular iOS workaround and why it's suddenly breaking my event handlers?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with `react-contextmenu v2.11.0`. It only happens with certain menuitems, not all. So something in the DOM is triggering this.